# Is there maximum number of .DBFs that can be joined using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.2

Is there a maximum number of .DBFs that can be joined using the Join Tool in ModelBuilder? I tried joining 480 .DBFs but results generated only 250 fields in the input table. Is this a glitch? I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't an issue with ArcGIS, but rather a limitation of the DBF fille format.  DBF files have a maximum of 255 fields.

See: [Maximum number of rows and columns can a DBF file contain](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5dc6f17-118b-49df-8067-660ec7eae0a3/maximum-number-of-rows-and-columns-can-a-dbf-file-contain?forum=visualfoxprogeneral)